# Multi dimensional array creation for sending values to json in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am going to save images in webservices for that I encode the image and passed as string(for single image).For multiple image I need the array for saving encoded image string and image type. I already have the array with some parameters. Now I want the multi dimensional array for saving image details.

The format is

```
diary image=>[0]=>imagedata,imagetype
           =>[1]=>imagedata,imagetype
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multidimentional array in android, cause it consume more meory always try to avoid have look [here..](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)

You may use

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> imagesList=new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String,String> image1Map=new HashMap<String,String>();
image1Map.put("imageData","image data goes here");
image1Map.put("imageType","image typegoes here");
image1Map.put("image","image goes here");
imagesList.add(image1Map);
```